# How to read gitlab-workhorse logs?

Tags: log-files, compression, gitlab, omnibus

I am running gitlab omnibus installation on local server.

There are certain incidents which happened and would like to see the logs in gitlab-workhorse.

The files in `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse` from previous day are named something like the follows `@4000****.s` and `@4000****.u`.

When I tail the `current` I see the logs human readable but not the files with `*.s` or `*.u` extension (I am guessing these are compressed log files).

Wondering how i can read/uncompress them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zcat` to read these files.

Credits to Mark Fletcher (@markglenfletcher at https://gitlab.com/)